# What are some inventions from the Chinese Han Dynasty?

Tags: china

I am researching about the Chinese Han Dynasty, and I was looking at some inventions they made. I have a list of them right now that include the kite, endless chain for irrigation, the iron plow, story tellers, paper and printing, ship rudder and the compass. Are there any that I missed?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: H:SE is based on the assumption that there is an authoritative answer for every question; how will you select the authoritative answer for this question?  And all questions should address why the relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Science_and_technology) page is inadequate.

Comment: There is a whole book series on that! It has if memory serves well at least 14 titles called chapters, one devoted to ceramics, one to mechanical contraptions... It's huge and still ongoing. Not as big as the Pauli, but huge.

Comment: [Joseph Needham: Science and Civilisation in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_and_Civilisation_in_China) currently has 7 volumes, distributed on 27 books. Ceramics is Vol6 Part12, mechanical contraptions are Vol4 Part2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wheelbarrow**

According to "Needham, Volume 4, Part 2, 263-267", the wheelbarrow was an invention of the Hans chinese.

[Wikipedia, History, China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelbarrow#History)

> The earliest wheelbarrows with archaeological evidence in the form of a one-wheel cart come from second century Han Dynasty Emperor Hui's tomb murals and brick tomb reliefs.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelbarrow#cite_note-needham_volume_4_part_2_263_267-1)

[Link for photograph by Dadarot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelbarrow#/media/File:Wine_shop,_China,_collected_at_Yihe,_Pehgzhou_City,_Eastern_Han_dynasty,_25-220_AD,_tomb_tile_-_Sichuan_Provincial_Museum_-_Chengdu,_China_-_DSC04779.jpg)
[image: Han dynasty tomb brick showing a wheelbarrow]

**Seismometer**

A seismometer is an instrument that responds to ground motions, such as caused by earthquakes, volcanic eruptions, and explosions.
According to "Dragons and toads: the Chinese seismoscope of BC. 132", from the Wikipedia link below, it was also another invention of the Hans Chinese.

[Wikipedia, History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismometer#History)

> The first seismometer was made in China during the 2nd century.[9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKtSI.jpg)

[Photograph by Kowloonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismometer#/media/File:EastHanSeismograph.JPG) 
[image: Replica of Zhang Heng's seismoscope Houfeng Didong Yi]

**Blast furnace**

A blast furnace is a type of metallurgical furnace used for smelting to produce industrial metals, and it is yet another Chinese invention dating to around 800BC, according to "The Earliest Use of Iron in China" by Donald B. Wagner.

[Wikipedia, history, china](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_furnace#History)

> Archaeological evidence shows that bloomeries appeared in China around 800 BC.

[image: Chinese fining and blast furnace, Tiangong Kaiwu, 1637.]

Comment: What justifies your arbitrary choice? Why not their code of laws?

Comment: @Trish The Chinese invented law? I was unaware of this. Thank you for the heads up, i'll look in to it.

Comment: no, but each dynasty did create new laws. Which usually *is* a huge accomplishment.